# How to extract the values from JSON string inside google sheet that repeats multiple times?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following table:
[image]

and I want the output to be this
[image]

I can't seem to find any resources on this.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about using Google Apps Script as follows?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When your showing sample image is used, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(J2:J)` to the cell "K2". By this, the script is run.

```js
function SAMPLE(values) {
  const headers = ["item_description", "quantity"]; // Please check each value again.
  const temp = values.map(([j]) => j ? JSON.parse(j.trim()).flatMap(e => headers.flatMap(h => e[h] || null)) : []);
  const max = Math.max(...temp.map(e => e.length));
  return temp.map(e => [...e, ...Array(max - e.length).fill(null)]);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used using the sample values, the following sample situation is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- If you want to fix the values to the cells, how about the following sample script? When this script is run, the values are retrieved from column "J". And, the converted values are put from column "K". The same result with the above script is obtained.

  ```js
  function myFunction() {
    const headers = ["item_description", "quantity"];// Please check each value again.
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheet name.
    const values = sheet.getRange("J2:J" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    const temp = values.map(([j]) => j ? JSON.parse(j.trim()).flatMap(e => headers.flatMap(h => e[h] || null)) : []);
    const max = Math.max(...temp.map(e => e.length));
    const res = temp.map(e => [...e, ...Array(max - e.length).fill(null)]);
    sheet.getRange(2, 11, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)